# Compile sass to css in Visual Studio 2019 using gulp

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, visual-studio-2019, gulp-sass, task-runner-explorer

Ok, so I followed procedure on how how to compile sass files to css file in Visual Studio 2019 (asp.net core 2.2), but somehow I am getting the following error

```
Failed to run "C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
fs.js:119
    throw err;
    ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:806:3)
    at Object.getInstalledBinaries (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:131:13)
    at foundBinariesList (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:20:15)
    at foundBinaries (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:15:5)
    at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:45:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
```

So far I have created package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
     "gulp-sass": "4.0.2"
  }
}
```

and gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./SASS/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./CSS'));
});

//Default task
gulp.task('default', ['build-css']);
```

So according to error message, the following directory doesnt exist C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass\vendor

I am seeing C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\Admin2Mvc\Admin2Mvc\node_modules\node-sass directory, but not /vendor subdirectory inside.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where in project you create a package.json file ?

Comment: First of all gulp and the gulp-sass plugin should be added as a development dependencies. I would suggest deleting the node_modules directory to start fresh and the package.json file. Then using a command prompt on the project directory do: npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-sass